# A couple of polr Issues for ordinal regression with ordinal independent variables

Tags: r, regression, ordinal-data, polr

I am having trouble using polr for a ordinal regression because I also have ordinal independent variables. Looking online it looks like I should either convert them to categorical dummy variables or go the numerical continuous route. Does anyone have any advice for which is the best option?

I have been able to get the model to run but R runs several polynomials for the independent ordinal variables (L, Q, C etc.). Is there a way to only have one run or is the best option to lose the order and make them continuous.

One model example is that the dependent variable is willingness to work (very unwilling, unwilling, neutral, willing, very willing) and one of the independent variables is level of work experience (none, some, moderate, significant).

Q132o <- factor(first_wave$Q132, levels=c("VU", "SU", "N", "SS", "VS"), ordered=TRUE)
Q33o <- factor(first_wave$Q33, levels=c("N", "So", "Mo", "Si"), ordered=TRUE)
MF6 <- polr(Q132o~ Q33o, data = first_wave, Hess = TRUE)

> summary_MF6 <- coef(summary(MF6))
> pvalMF6 <- pnorm(abs(summary_MF6[, "t value"]),lower.tail = FALSE)* 2
> summary_MF6 <- cbind(summary_MF6, "p value" = round(pvalMF6,3))
> summary_MF6
> Value Std. Error    t value p value
> Q33o.L    0.39314058  0.4363851  0.9009029   0.368
> Q33o.Q   -0.16563280  0.3518657 -0.4707274   0.638
> Q33o.C   -0.34313835  0.2858676 -1.2003399   0.230

Another issue is that when I don't have the factors ordered I am told that the model is "rank deficient and that coefficients are dropped"

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this question? I'm working through the same challenge.